# get value Array in Array vue for menu and submenu js

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to retrieve data in an array in an array list. The case here is that I want to create a dynamic menu with a parent menu and submenu. I had trouble after getting the parent menu but I couldn't get the submenu. here's the data I'm dealing with

[image: This construction data]

and this data console:

[image: this data console for get subMenu]

and this example design menu and submenu

[image]

and this code for get menu parent and submenu

```html
 <v-list
      expand
      shaped
      class="vertical-nav-menu-items pr-5"
    >

      <nav-menu-group
        v-for="(item, i) in newList"
        :key="i"
        :title="item.name"
        :icon="icons.mdiHomeOutline"
      >
      <nav-menu-link
        v-for="(item, i) in newList"
        :key="i"
        :title="item.name"
        :icon="icons.mdiHomeOutline"
      />
       </nav-menu-group>
    </v-list>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like following snippet:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      newList: [
        {id: 1, name: 'Beranda', parentNavId: null},
        {id: 2, name: 'Admin', parentNavId: null, subMenu: [{id: 1, name: 'Menage Users', parentNavId: 2},{id: 2, name: 'Menage Members', parentNavId: 2}]}
      ]
    }
  }
})

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <v-list
      expand
      shaped
      class="vertical-nav-menu-items pr-5"
    >
  <v-list-group
    v-for="(item, i) in newList"
    :key="i"
    no-action
  >
    <template v-slot:activator>
        <v-list-item-content>
          <v-list-item-title v-text="item.name"></v-list-item-title>
        </v-list-item-content>
      </template>
      <v-list-item
        v-for="(it, i) in item.subMenu"
        :key="i"
      >
        <v-list-item-content>
          <v-list-item-title v-text="it.name"></v-list-item-title>
        </v-list-item-content>
      </v-list-item>
    </v-list-group>
  </v-list>
</div>
```